# Guardar imagen en MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, guardar, input-file

Estoy realizando un proyecto para mi universidad. Es una pagina web con un formulario, en uno de los campos se tiene que subir una imagen y guardarla en MySQL. El problema es que al querer guardarla me la pone como null o a veces me inserta sólo un espacio en blanco. Como si el `<input type="file">` estuviese vacio. Espero me puedan ayudar, les muestro el codigo del Form y del archivo php.
Ya intenté quitar la función y que mande a otra pagina para hacer el registro pero tampoco funciona. En un articulo lei que a veces los archivos jquery pueden hacer que no funcione el `<input="file">` pero sólo uso jequery de bootstrap, los quité pero aun asi no guarda la imagen.

Index.php:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-10">
            <fieldset class="form-control">
                <table width="100%">
                    <h3>Solicitar Reparación</h3>
                    <hr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="60%">
                            <b><label for="Nombre">Nombre del solicitante</label></b>
                            <input type="text" name="Nombre" class="form-control" required="">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <b><label for="Zona">Zona</label></b>
                            <select class="form-control" required="" name="Zona">
                                <option value="Seleccione">Seleccione</option>
                                <option value="Urbana">Urbana</option>
                                <option value="Rural">Rural</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b><label for="Direccion">Dirección</label></b>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="Direccion" placeholder="Introduce la dirección donde se encuentra el desperfecto" required=""></textarea>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <b><label for="TipoDesperfecto">Tipo de Desperfecto</label></b>
                            <select class="form-control" required="" name="TipoDesperfecto">
                                <option value="Seleccione">Seleccione</option>
                                <option value="Alumbrado">Alumbrado Publico</option>
                                <option value="Baches">Baches</option>
                                <option value="Parques">Servicio a Parques</option>
                                <option value="Basura">Recolección de Basura</option>
                                <option value="Fuga">Fuga de Agua</option>
                                <option value="Otro">Otro</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b><label for="Desperfecto">Imagen del Desperfecto</label></b>
                            <input type="file" name="Desperfecto" class="form-control" required="">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <b><label for="Descripcion">Descripción</label></b>
                            <textarea class="form-control" required="" name="Descripcion" placeholder="Introduce una descripción del Desperfecto"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br>
                <center><input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Solicitar" class="btn btn-primary"></center>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <?php
            require('Solicitud.php');
            if(isset($_POST['Enviar'])){
               RegistrarSolicitud();
            }
        ?>
    </form>
```

Index.php:

```
<?php
function RegistrarSolicitud(){
    require('Config/conn.php');
    try{
        //Consulta para insertar datos en la Base de Datos
        $ConsultaMYSQL = "INSERT INTO solicitud (FechaSolicitud, Nombre, Zona, Direccion, TipoDesperfecto, Imagen, Descripcion, Status) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        //Prepara la consulta de inserción
        $ComandoMYSQL = $Conn->prepare($ConsultaMYSQL);

        //Se obtienen los datos del formulario
        $Nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
        $Zona = $_POST['Zona'];
        $Direccion = $_POST['Direccion'];
        $TipoDesperfecto = $_POST['TipoDesperfecto'];
        $Desperfecto = null;
        $Descripcion = $_POST['Descripcion'];
        $Status = "En Proceso";
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Chihuahua');
        $FechaSolicitud = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $ComandoMYSQL->bind_param("sssssbss", $FechaSolicitud, $Nombre, $Zona, $Direccion, $TipoDesperfecto, $Desperfecto, $Descripcion, $Status);

        $ComandoMYSQL->send_long_data(9, file_get_contents($_FILES['Desperfecto']['tmp_name']));

        $ComandoMYSQL->execute();

        echo "Solicitud Enviada";
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Error ". $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Generalmente los archivos vienen en un array, por lo tanto, deberías acceder a la clave `0`, imaginando que hay un solo archivo: `$_FILES[0]['Desperfecto']['tmp_name']`, si no te funciona, haz una **depuración**  mediante `var_dump($_FILES);` y agrégala a la pregunta para ver con qué estás trabajando exactamente.

Comment: Le colocaste enctype="multipart/form-data" a la etiqueta del formulario?

Answer (score 1):

A. Cedano, Gracias. Ya lo pude solucionar. Donde tenia un 9 en el `send_long_data()` era un 5 ya que es la posición en la que se encuentra en la inserción de MySQL.